# Bootstrap data-toggle radio button/Checkbox checked property

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I saw many questions related to this issue. But that questions are not related to my scenario.

Below is my radio button design in JSP page. To add **active** class in label i used JSTL tags.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">

  <label class="btn btn-primary  <c:if test=" ${initialExamScreenTwoForm.cervicalSpineHeadTiltRight==1} ">active</c:if>">
    <form:checkbox path="cervicalSpineHeadTiltRight" id="cervicalSpineHeadTiltRight_id" value="1" autocomplete="off" />Right
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary <c:if test=" ${initialExamScreenTwoForm.cervicalSpineHeadTiltLeft==1} ">active</c:if>">
    <form:checkbox id="cervicalSpineHeadTiltLeft_id" path="cervicalSpineHeadTiltLeft" value="1" autocomplete="off" />Left
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary <c:if test=" ${initialExamScreenTwoForm.cervicalSpineHeadTiltNormal==1} ">active</c:if>">
    <form:checkbox id="cervicalSpineHeadTiltNormal_id" path="cervicalSpineHeadTiltNormal" value="1" autocomplete="off" />Normal
  </label>

</div>
```

The **active** class is added fine. But checked property is not added to the radio button.

While loading from back end it's working fine. When i selecting other value, In front end it's showing like selected (i.e active class was added) but checked property is not added to the button. So it's sending old value to the back end.

In bootstrap, using like this

```
c.prototype.toggle = function() {
  var a = !0,
    b = this.$element.closest('[data-toggle="buttons"]');
  if (b.length) {
    var c = this.$element.find("input");
    "radio" == c.prop("type") && (c.prop("checked") && this.$element.hasClass("active") ? a = !1 : b.find(".active").removeClass("active")), a && c.prop("checked", !this.$element.hasClass("active")).trigger("change")
  }
  a && this.$element.toggleClass("active")
};
```

I can't figure out what is the issue. Please help me to find what i did wrong.

Comment: you also need to place the JSTL condition in checkbox input for checked property

Comment: While loading from back end it's working fine. When i selecting other value in front end it's showing like selected **(i.e active class was added)** but checked property is not added to the button.

Comment: what bootStrap JS version you are using?

Comment: Current version is 3.3.6 there is lot of things changed in new version. can you please update and check it

Comment: okay.. i have one doubt, if i changed the version it will affect the any design ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102431/discussion-between-kp-singh-and-user3141852).

Comment: Thanks @kp singh,, i updated the latest version code for only **data-toggle="buttons"**,, It's Working Fine

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in version of **bootstrap.js(i am using 3.2.0)**. I can't update full code, because i added the additional code for my project.

So i Updated the **data-toggle="buttons"** part in bootstrap.min.js it's working fine. The Code i changed is.

```
c.prototype.toggle = function() {
  var a = !0,
      b = this.$element.closest('[data-toggle="buttons"]');
  if (b.length) {
      var c = this.$element.find("input");
      "radio" == c.prop("type") ? (c.prop("checked") && (a = !1), b.find(".active").removeClass("active"), this.$element.addClass("active")) : "checkbox" == c.prop("type") && (c.prop("checked") !== this.$element.hasClass("active") && (a = !1), this.$element.toggleClass("active")), c.prop("checked", this.$element.hasClass("active")), a && c.trigger("change")
  } else this.$element.attr("aria-pressed", !this.$element.hasClass("active")), this.$element.toggleClass("active")
};
var d = a.fn.button;
a.fn.button = b, a.fn.button.Constructor = c, a.fn.button.noConflict = function() {
  return a.fn.button = d, this
}, a(document).on("click.bs.button.data-api", '[data-toggle^="button"]', function(c) {
  var d = a(c.target);
  d.hasClass("btn") || (d = d.closest(".btn")), b.call(d, "toggle"), a(c.target).is('input[type="radio"]') || a(c.target).is('input[type="checkbox"]') || c.preventDefault()
}).on("focus.bs.button.data-api blur.bs.button.data-api", '[data-toggle^="button"]', function(b) {
  a(b.target).closest(".btn").toggleClass("focus", /^focus(in)?$/.test(b.type))
})
}
```

Thanks @kp singh